# How can I add a yearly recurring event on the last Saturday in a specific month?

Tags: google-calendar

Just as the title says, how can I add a recurring event on the last Saturday in August in Google Calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your first event on the appropriate day.

Then, on the "Event edit" screen, open the "Repeat..." menu.

1. For **Repeats:**, choose "Monthly"
2. For **Repeat every:**, choose "12" months
3. For **Repeat by:**, choose "day of the week"
4. Choose whatever other options you need, then click "Done"

[image: Google Calendar screen shot]

This *might* get a little tricky if a month has only four Saturdays and that's what you use, as Google might not know whether to select "fourth Saturday" or "last Saturday".

Comment: This still works in 2023, although the interface has changed slightly. After creating the event and navigating to 'Repeats', you can now select either 'fourth Saturday' or 'last Saturday' of the month.